# Update the input text field on click of a button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a Facelets page where I have a `p:inputText` field for student ID. I also have a `p:commandButton` next to this input text field and I want that when I click this button then then a random student id be generated and displayed in this text field. My Facelets file code is:

```
<td width="15%"><p:inputText id="Student ID" value="#{StudentData.id}"></p:inputText></td>
<td width="13%"><p:commandButton value="Generate ID" action="#{StudentID.id}" ajax="false" >  </p:commandButton></td>
```

The `StudentID.id` contains code which generates a random number as in:

```
public class StudentID implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    public StudentID() {

    }


     public int getId() {  
            return id;  
        }  

     @PostConstruct
       public void init() {

        Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 10;
        int High = 10000;
         id = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    }

}
```

The code generates random ID but how can I update the input text field on the Facelets page with that random id? I basically want that once I click "Generate ID" button the input text field next to it should get updated with the random number generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<h:form id="RandomIDGenerationForm">

<h:panelGroup id="StudentIDGeneration">
    <h:inputText id="Student ID" value="#{StudentData.id}"></p:inputText>
</h:panelGroup>
<p:commandButton value="Generate ID" action="#{StudentData.generateRandomID()}" update="StudentIDGeneration">  </p:commandButton>

</form>
```

The managed bean:

```
public class StudentData implements Serializable {
        
    private int id;
    public StudentData() {
        //default contructor
    }
     
    public int getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  
    
    public void generateRandomID() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 10;
        int High = 10000;
        id = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    }
}
```